# How to display only the international airports in google maps without getting any domestic or customs airports?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers

I used "airports" keyword in Google maps to display international airports. But I'm also getting the domestic and custom airports. Can any one tell me what is the correct keyword to get only the international airports?

This is my code:

```
var request = {location: source, radius: 50000, types: ['airport']};
```

Comment: Why maps-api-2? Which API version are you using? Using Android? With what service? Geocoding? Anyway... There is an *airport* address component type - nothing else. You would need external data to have more details.

Comment: it's google-maps api v3

Answer (score 0):

In order to filter further @MrUpsidown is correct, you need an external data source.  I would imagine there is a free KML file available which can be used to display only international airports.  Here is an example I [found](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/rec.aviation.soaring/EOBD9OO2Qe4).

Here is the [syntax](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/layer-kml) for displaying a KML file.

Comment: I am not asking about the KML layers. I am asking about the "keyword" to display only the "international airports", without any domestic or custom airports

Comment: It is not possible to select only "international airports" with the current places api which is why i suggested an alternative approach.